# Emacs: how to make a specific buffer appear after current is killed?

Tags: emacs

We have `buf-1`, other buffers, `buf-2`.
I `(kill-buffer buf-1)`, how can I reliably make `buf-2` appear instead of 1.
And I mean how does Emacs do it, not just make my hook for this.

From the source code, `kill-buffer` calls:

```
+replace_buffer_in_windows (buffer);
|
+-+(switch-to-prev-buffer window 'kill)
  |
  +-+(window-prev-buffers window)      and other functions
```

I've played with `set-window-prev-buffers` and `set-window-next-buffers`, but no luck.
At least "`this_code` works for me" will help.

**EDIT**
Technically what I want is: to "remember" an order in what Emacs will open buffers after `kill-buffer` is called. And then be able to recreate the same window (in a new Emacs session already) so that if I call `kill-buffer` in this new window I will get the same result.

Now to "remember" I need to understand how Emacs itself does this choice (what to show after kill). Only because of this I said that a custom hook will probably not help.

Comment: Please clarify your post.  By "appear," do you mean "make buf-2 show up in the window where buf-2 used to be"?  Are you trying to do this from within a function, or as an interactive command?  Are `buf-1` and `buf-2` hard-coded names, or just stand-ins?  And what do you mean by the "Emacs way"?  Hooks are pretty emacsy, so if that's not the "Emacs way," then you'll need to explain what you mean a bit more.

Comment: Why do you say hook is not the Emacs way?

Comment: How do we know what `buf-2`?  `(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook (lambda () (if (get-buffer buf-2) (switch-to-buffer buf-2))))`  In other words, you will need something like `(let ((buf-2 . . .`  And, the hook can be made buffer-local by adding an additional `t` at the tail end of the `(add-hook . . . t)`

Comment: Alternatively, what works for me, is creating my own `lawlist-kill-buffer` function and linking it to my favorite keyboard shortcut -- it has things like `(if (get-buffer . . .`, and things like `(let* ((to-be-killed (buffer-name))) (if (eq (with-current-buffer to-be-killed major-mode) 'wl-draft-mode) . . .`, and things like `(when (get-buffer "*scratch*") (find-file (concat root.d ".scratch")) (kill-buffer "*scratch*"))`, and things like `(if (string= "Attempt to delete the sole visible or iconified frame" `

Comment: I added some clarification on what I'm actually doing and why a hook for 2 particular buffers will not help. Will look into window.el. And yes, I know that hooks are "Emacs way", it was just misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hooks are "The Emacs Way":

In `buf-1`, do this:

```
(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook
  (lambda ()
    (set-window-next-buffers nil (cons "buf-2" (window-next-buffers)))))
```

The code is untested, so you might need to play with it to get it to work (e.g., you will probably have to replace `"buf-2"` with `(get-buffer "buf-2")`).

Please see [`window.el`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/window.el) for inspiration.

Comment: I'll mark this as correct since the problem is in another part of my code. And I think `set-window-next-buffers` (or prev) is what should work now for me.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to like my answer, but, well, it's my answer:

Switch to the buffer you want **first**, then do `C-x k M-n M-n RET` to delete the one that was current previously.